# IE support for DOM importNode

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, dom

I've been looking arround the web, and I'm fairly sure I already know the answer ("no"), but I'd like to check:

Does IE support importNode() yet? Is there a better alternative than walking the DOM and creating nodes? (I've seen [the clasic article by Anthony Holdener](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/crossbrowserscripting/) but its more than a year old now, and I'm hoping that either IE has evolved, or someone has another workarround)

Thanks.

Comment: Here's a [related question with an implementation](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6075604/405017).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I haven't heard this has changed yet, and in a [recent post](http://ejohn.org/blog/nodename-case-sensitivity/) by John Resig, he states:

> Internet Explorer doesn't support importNode or adoptNode

Also see this A List Apart article on [cross-browser importnode()](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/crossbrowserscripting/) as it includes a specific work-around for Internet Explorer.

To quote for posterity,

> The solution to all of my problems was to not use a DOM method after all, and instead use my own implementation. Here, in all of its glory, is my final solution to the importNode() problem coded in a cross-browser compliant way: (Line wraps marked » —Ed.)

```
if (!document.ELEMENT_NODE) {
  document.ELEMENT_NODE = 1;
  document.ATTRIBUTE_NODE = 2;
  document.TEXT_NODE = 3;
  document.CDATA_SECTION_NODE = 4;
  document.ENTITY_REFERENCE_NODE = 5;
  document.ENTITY_NODE = 6;
  document.PROCESSING_INSTRUCTION_NODE = 7;
  document.COMMENT_NODE = 8;
  document.DOCUMENT_NODE = 9;
  document.DOCUMENT_TYPE_NODE = 10;
  document.DOCUMENT_FRAGMENT_NODE = 11;
  document.NOTATION_NODE = 12;
}

document._importNode = function(node, allChildren) {
  switch (node.nodeType) {
    case document.ELEMENT_NODE:
      var newNode = document.createElement(node »
.nodeName);
      /* does the node have any attributes to add? */
      if (node.attributes && node.attributes »
.length > 0)
        for (var i = 0; il = node.attributes.length;i < il)
          newNode.setAttribute(node.attributes[i].nodeName, 
          node.getAttribute(node.attributes[i++].nodeName));
      /* are we going after children too, and does the node have any? */
      if (allChildren && node.childNodes && node.childNodes.length > 0)
        for (var i = 0; il = node.childNodes.length; i < il)
          newNode.appendChild(document._importNode(node.childNodes[i++], allChildren));
      return newNode;
      break;
    case document.TEXT_NODE:
    case document.CDATA_SECTION_NODE:
    case document.COMMENT_NODE:
      return document.createTextNode(node.nodeValue);
      break;
  }
};
```

> Here it is in use:

```
var newNode = null, importedNode = null;

newNode = xhrResponse.responseXML.getElementsByTagName('title')[0].childNodes[0];
if (newNode.nodeType != document.ELEMENT_NODE)
  newNode = newNode.nextSibling;
if (newNode) {
  importedNode = document._importNode(newNode, true);
  document.getElementById('divTitleContainer').appendChild(importedNode);
  if (!document.importNode)
    document.getElementById('divTitleContainer').innerHTML = document.getElementById('divTitleContainer').innerHTML;
}
```

Comment: This is a good general approach, but you'll want to `document.createComment` in response to a `COMMENT_NODE`; turning it into a text node probably isn't a good idea. There are also many problems with using `getAttribute`/`setAttribute` on HTML elements in IE, unfortunately; if you're cloning forms the `name` may be a problem, and `onX` attributes and inline `style`​s aren't going to work in a useful way (best avoid them). Also any `<script>` elements will get re-executed when appended to any parent node.

Comment: @bobince: excellent point about the comment nodes. get/setAttribute can be a problem on IE6 sometimes, though, I haven't noticed significant problems on IE7+ with that particular pair of functions (lots to complain about otherwise, though).

Comment: To also support namespaced attributes, use setAttributeNS and getAttributeNS instead of setAttribute and getAttribute.

Answer (score 5):

There is a function document.importNode() in Internet Explorer 9 DOM API. However, IE9 throws a script error when it's called

> SCRIPT16386: No such interface supported

Also there is need to define namespace of source node (e.g., when we want to import SVG - [In IE9, Imported nodes do not seem to be recognized as SVG Elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9281902/in-ie9-imported-nodes-do-not-seem-to-be-recognized-as-svg-elements))

[Phrogz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/405017/phrogz) suggested [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6075604/1193727) useful workaround. However, when we import element which has special namespace (declared in xmlns attribute, e.g. `<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" …>…</svg>`) there will be error in `clone.setAttributeNS(a.namespaceURI,a.nodeName,a.nodeValue)` because namespaceURI for attribute xmlns is null.

There is workaround which work for me:

```
var newNode;
try {
  newNode = document.importNode(sourceDocumentElement, true);
}
catch(e) {
  newNode = importNode(sourceDocumentElement, true);
}

function importNode(node, allChildren) {
  switch (node.nodeType) {
    case document.ELEMENT_NODE:
      var newNode = document.createElementNS(node.namespaceURI, node.nodeName);
      if(node.attributes && node.attributes.length > 0)
        for(var i = 0, il = node.attributes.length; i < il; i++)
          newNode.setAttribute(node.attributes[i].nodeName, node.getAttribute(node.attributes[i].nodeName));
      if(allChildren && node.childNodes && node.childNodes.length > 0)
        for(var i = 0, il = node.childNodes.length; i < il; i++)
          newNode.appendChild(importNode(node.childNodes[i], allChildren));
      return newNode;
      break;
    case document.TEXT_NODE:
    case document.CDATA_SECTION_NODE:
    case document.COMMENT_NODE:
      return document.createTextNode(node.nodeValue);
      break;
  }
}
```

Comment: This works great for me, but I'm having a problem where <image> elements are showing up as broken images (in IE9). Any idea why this would happen? I have verified that the image URLs are valid, so that is definitely not the problem. Thanks!

Comment: In case anyone is interested, I [solved the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14593520/ie9-importing-inline-svg-image-elements-broken).

Answer (score -1):

For a lighter-weight solution (provided you don't mind adding the dependency), you could always use jQuery:

```
$(dom_to_import_into).find('element-to-import-into').append($(dom_to_import).clone());
```

This will add `dom_to_import` at the end of `'element-to-import-into'`.

Comment: MAY NOT WORK in IE. Depends what you are trying to do. I suspect the original poster is using importNode because s/he is copying from an external document (e.g. iframe or window.open). As such, using jQuery's append() will still fail on IE. HierarchyRequestError.