# Import SVG node into another document in IE9

Tags: javascript, svg, internet-explorer-9

After fetching an SVG document using XHR I need to append a portion of it from the `responseXML` document into the current document. Using this code works on Safari/Chrome/FireFox, but does not work on IE9:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest;
xhr.open('get','stirling4.svg',true);
xhr.onreadystatechange = function(){
  if (xhr.readyState != 4) return;
  var g = xhr.responseXML.getElementsByTagName('g')[2];
  var p = document.getElementsByTagName('path')[0];
  p.parentNode.insertBefore(document.importNode(g,true),p);
};
xhr.send();
```

IE9 throws a script error when calling importNode:

> SCRIPT16386: No such interface supported

I found [a question](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/iewebdevelopment/thread/4236f1a1-746c-44b5-b41a-f84e58f20458) where someone else reports a similar problem. You can see a live example of this problem [on my website](http://phrogz.net/SVG/fetch_fragment.svg). (The SVG file itself displays a fractal, uses XHR to fetch [another SVG file](http://phrogz.net/SVG/fetch_fragment.svg), uses one technique to manually import one of the nodes and then attempts to use `importNode` to import another node. One Chrome, Safari, or Firefox you see two grey diamonds imported into the document, while on IE9 only the first diamond works.)

How can I make `importNode` work with IE9?

Comment: Related question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1811116/ie-support-for-dom-importnode

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a workaround solution that manually 'imports' the node by using a custom function to recursively clone all portions of it instead of using `importNode`. This code is used on [my example page](http://phrogz.net/SVG/fetch_fragment.svg) to import one of the two shapes.

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest;
xhr.open('get','stirling4.svg',true);
xhr.onreadystatechange = function(){
  if (xhr.readyState != 4) return;
  var g = xhr.responseXML.getElementsByTagName('g')[2];
  var p = document.getElementsByTagName('path')[0];
  p.parentNode.insertBefore(cloneToDoc(g),p);
};
xhr.send();

function cloneToDoc(node,doc){
  if (!doc) doc=document;
  var clone = doc.createElementNS(node.namespaceURI,node.nodeName);
  for (var i=0,len=node.attributes.length;i<len;++i){
    var a = node.attributes[i];
    clone.setAttributeNS(a.namespaceURI,a.nodeName,a.nodeValue);
  }
  for (var i=0,len=node.childNodes.length;i<len;++i){
    var c = node.childNodes[i];
    clone.insertBefore(
      c.nodeType==1 ? cloneToDoc(c,doc) : doc.createTextNode(c.nodeValue),
      null
    );
  }
  return clone;
}
```

Comment: I'm happy to accept a better solution if someone can find a workaround that allows `importNode` to work correctly.