# IE9 importing inline SVG <image> elements broken

Tags: javascript, svg, internet-explorer-9

I am using [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9883539/494954) to import an SVG doc into a page, and it works pretty well, but in IE9, none of the `<image>` tags work after the import (they show up as broken images, even though their `xlink:href` attribute is correct). Why does this happen, and is there any way around it? Here's a simple [test page](http://lakenen.com/svg-test/index.html). It works fine in Chrome, FF, etc, but not in IE9.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The js implementation of `importNode` provided in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9883539/494954) doesn't properly set namespaced attributes, it should use `setAttributeNS` to set `xlink:href` correctly. This [other implementation of importNode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6075566/import-svg-node-into-another-document-in-ie9/6075604#6075604) seems to handle that, have you tried using that one instead?

Comment: I did try that, but it gives `SCRIPT5022: DOM Exception: NAMESPACE_ERR (14)` on the line `clone.setAttributeNS(a.namespaceURI,a.nodeName,a.nodeValue);`.

Comment: I'm guessing that's about the xmlns:xlink attribute? or is that for any prefixed attribute?

Comment: Seems like it happens for all prefixed attributes.

Comment: After further inspection, it seems to throw that error only on the actual `<svg>` element, for the following attributes: `xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"` and `xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"`. If I wrap that line in a try...catch block (doing nothing on catch), it seems to import the doc just fine.

Comment: I'm accepting your answer, because I think you're correct. Though, I'm still confused as to why those attributes are causing namespace errors.

Answer (score 5):

Apparently if I drop the `xlink:` and just use `href`, if fixes the problem in IE9, but breaks it in Chrome, etc. Weird! If anyone knows why, I'd be happy to accept your answer. See [test 2](http://lakenen.com/svg-test/index2.html).

**Adding** `href`, ***in addition to*** `xlink:href` **fixes the issue everywhere.**

Comment: Thanks for adding the _real_ fix! It worked for me too...  `<svg><use ng-attr-xlink:href="{{expression}}" xlink:href="" ng-attr-href="{{expression}}"></svg>`