# SVG use element refering external file doesn't work in Safari

Tags: html, svg, safari, xlink

I have a HTML file with inline SVG, which in turn refers to SVG elements in external SVG file with library elements. It uses a `<use>` elements with `xlink:href="Library.svg#libraryShapeID"`. It works as a breeze in Opera and Firefox, but doesn't work in Safari. I've made a simple test file here:

http://sasq.comyr.com/Stuff/SVG/test01.html

Is it some browser bug or am I doing something wrong?
How should I rewrite it to make it work in Safari too?

Answer (score 4):

There was a [bug about this on Webkit](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=12499) but it has been fixed for the Version: 420+ BUT the bug for [Fragment identifier](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=65344) is still not solved.

Someone gave an answer: [Importing external SVG (with WebKit)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5411856/importing-external-svg-with-webkit) using XMLHttpRequest. Quite unfortunate but in the meantime, I guess working.

Comment: Is this bug in the current Safari? I am on Version 5.1.7 (6534.57.2), and this still seems to be a problem.

Comment: @supertrue As I said the Bug 65344 - Make external URL references work is still opened.

Answer (score 1):

I realize that this is an old question. But as this method of using SVGs has become more popular these days, I wrote a [polyfill](https://github.com/Keyamoon/svgxuse) to make this technique work in browsers that fail to load the external SVG by default. At the time of writing this, IE9+ doesn't support referencing external SVGs in use elements. The polyfill that I wrote is quite simple and lightweight; it detects whether the SVG has failed to load and if so, sends a GET request to fetch it. It will then prepend it to body.

I hope you find it useful. I would appreciate any feedback.

Comment: Thanks for your great work! svg4everybody failed on recent iPads, but your script worked!