# Reuse objects defined in <defs>?

Tags: html, svg

I wanted to write a logo in svg, but surprisingly found that I could not re-use objects defined in `<defs>...</defs>`. I tried them on Chrome.

Please see examples:

1. test1.html doesn't work, no rect was drawn.

   ```
   <!DOCTTYPE html>
   <html>
     <body>
       <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
            xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
            width="480" height="360">
         <defs>
           <rect id="helo" x="0" y="0" height="20" width="20" />
         </defs>
         <use xlink:href="#helo" />
       </svg>
     </body>
   </html>
   ```
2. BUT test2.svg works.

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0"?>
   <!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN"
                 "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
   <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
        xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
        width="480" height="360">
     <defs>
       <rect id="helo" x="0" y="0" height="20" width="20" />
     </defs>
     <use xlink:href="#helo" />
   </svg>
   ```

What's needed to make the test1.html work?
Many thanks:)

Comment: Also `DOCTYPE` is misspelled as `DOCTTYPE` in the non-working example.

Comment: almost as common as `DUCTTAPE` / `DUCKTAPE` :)

Comment: Thanks. but it doesn't work either way:P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that this is a bug in Webkit:
[Importing external SVG (with WebKit)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5411856/importing-external-svg-with-webkit)
https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=12499

If you're going to create an SVG icon, I would make it in a separate .svg file and then add it into the HTML with the `object` tag. That would be better anyway since if you make changes to the SVG file and it will change all instance on your website.

Comment: Thanks Peter. Nice links. I m still studying those weird testsuits. For now I decide to use canvas instead:)

Answer (score 0):

The bug seems to have been fixed now however there is one important caveat here that when you are trying to re-use objects in the `defs` tag in SVG on a HTML page the `xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"` is important and must be added to the SVG tag. Without that the href isn't resolved.